# I want to compare my input csv file, with standard (template) csv file. such that, column headers also should be compared along with the data

Tags: java, csv, filecompare

scenario:

1. a std Transaction file (csv) will be there (file1.csv)
2. other file( file2.csv) assume its a output from other module,

TASK:  file1 & file2 should match (headers & data) both should match,

Comment: Nice, what is your question?

Comment: And where's your current code?

Comment: When you say match, you mean contents of file 1 equals contents of file 2?

Comment: @anacron,,  yes!!!  content of the file(headdder , data) both should match

Comment: compute the hash of both file 1 and file 2 and compare the hashes. Don't loop through the data..

Comment: @bub, if u can guide me to get the solution, it will be helpful... i am trying with fileinput stream and buffer read,,, im not able to get sol :(

Comment: @anacron.. can u give some more details plss,,, it will be helpful if u have code snippet

Comment: @NagashreeRao It will be helpful if you provide a code snippet of your own, showing what you've done and where you think the problem is.

Comment: Is this a one time task? Do you really need a programmatic solution?

Comment: @anacron,, thanks i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for equality of files using Hashes.

If the hash values of two files match, then the files are exactly same.

Most common hashing techniques are MD5 and SHA1. It would be suitable for most common purposes. (Unless you are using them for cryptographic or security purposes!)

Your JRE comes with the `java.security.MessageDigest` class that provides hashing.

Here is a sample code that you can use:

```
public class HashCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        byte[] file1Contents = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/path/to/file1.csv"));
        byte[] file2Contents = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/path/to/file2.csv"));

        String hashtext1 = computeHash(file1Contents);
        String hashtext2 = computeHash(file2Contents);
        System.out.println(hashtext1);
        System.out.println(hashtext2);
        System.out.println(hashtext1.equals(hashtext2));
    }

    public static String computeHash(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return computeHash(input.getBytes());
    }

    public static String computeHash(byte[] input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest hasher = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); //MD5 or SHA1
        hasher.reset();
        hasher.update(input);
        byte[] digest = hasher.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest);
        String hashtext = bigInt.toString(16); // The hashes are base-16 numbers
        // Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
        while(hashtext.length() < hasher.getDigestLength() ){
          hashtext = "0"+hashtext;   
        }
        return hashtext;
    }

}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can upvote it and/or accept it as the answer.